# Add a field with value to all existing Solr documents

Tags: java, solr, solr4

I want to add a field with value to all my existing Solr documents. I was searching a lot online but can't find a clear way to do it. I need to be able to search/filter documents by that field as well.

Edit: Added clarification - I want to update all existing documents with this new field and value as well.

Answer (score 0):

A default value that will be added automatically to any document that does not have a value in this field when it is indexed.

If this property is not specified, there is no default.
e.g.

```
<field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" />
```

Please refer the [Solr Documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/defining-fields.html)

Another option to it partial update of the documents as below

```
{
 "id": "123",
 "name" : "Solr Updates"
}
```

Lets add an author field to the document the field value would be a json object with `"set"` attribute and the field value

```
$ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
[
 {"id"       : "123",
  "author"   : {"set":"Robert Wark"}
 }
]'
```

Your new document will look like as below after you query

```
$ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/get?id=123
```

The updates document is :

```
{
 "doc" : {
    "id"    : "123",
    "name"  : "Solr Updates"
    "author": "Robert Wark"
 }
}
```

Please refer the below [Updating parts of DOcuments](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html)

Using Java and Solrj api it can be done as follows.

```
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
Map<String, String> partialUpdate = new HashMap<String, String>();
partialUpdate.put("set", "Robert Wark");
doc.addField("id", "123");
doc.addField("author", partialUpdate);
```

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough, I want to add a new field with a default value to all existing documents in Solr. This is just a new field definition that will be added to new documents. I want to update old documents with this new field and value as well.

Comment: Once you modify the schema.xml with new field(s), you need to reindex the data in order to have that field for the existing documents

Comment: I updated the answer as there is another alternative to it.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately it doesn't solve my issue as I don't have document definitions saved in schema.xml file. We have it mapped in our code in Java. As for the curl update command I added the field I wanted there alone (don't know what the id field is there in the code snippet you provided for, I don't want to update specific document, I want to update all of them). If that's the case, unfortunately I get (23) Failed writing body error.

Comment: It can be done in java as well with the help of solrJ api... Every document in solr has a field which determines its uniqueness...id is such a field...your document must be having such field

Answer (score 0):

For people who might have the same or similar problems in the future:
My Solr configuration was kept in Java, not in xml files, so I decided to do the whole update process in Java as well. First add the new field to the configuration, then read in a batch of documents, check if the new field value is null - it should be since we just added it, then set the field with new value and save. Do it in batches so you don't run out of memmory by reading in too many documents at once.